# Is it possible to insert check box in the NSTextView?

Tags: cocoa, checkbox, nstextview

How do i insert a check box in a nstextView?
Customize the NSTextAttachment?
ANY BODY CAN TELL IT?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it. Maybe it works. 
Initialize a check box. Then add it as a subview to the cell. [textfield.cell addSubview:box];